# Compound Views: How can the attributes be passed on? (Android)

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am creating a compound view out of 1 `ImageView`, 2 `TextView`s and 1 `Button`. I was successfully able to create and display the view. But the attributes of my compound view did not contain the attributes of the views it is made up of (1 `ImageView`, 2 `TextView`s and 1 `Button`).

I don't like the idea of creating custom attributes because I will pretty much have to redo the work someone else did for me.

Is there a way to make the attributes to be passed on?

For example: my compound view has an `ImageView` and the `ImageView` has an attribute called `src` which is the image source. But my compound view doesn't have any attributes like `src` to change the image source or to change the text in a `TextView`.

Comment: Can you give an example of one of these attributes that should be "passed on"?

Comment: so why cannot you use android: src?